# Maven Projection creation error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium

I am trying to learn Maven.

I have following JDK and Maven version

```
C:\Users\iXXXXXX>java -version
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

C:\Users\iXXXXXX>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-24T14:49:0
5-05:00)
Maven home: C:\Users\iXXXXXX\Documents\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_171, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

I have also set the Environment variables - JAVA_HOME, M2_HOME and edited the path variable to both the bin folders.

I am trying to create a new Maven Project in Eclipse in two ways but not successful. Looks like access or security issue but do not know how to resolve.

1. I am getting following error when I try to  create from File  New  Maven Project  Entering Group Id and Artifact Id  Finish.

---

```
"Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not write artifact lastUpdated status
C:\Users\i716181\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\archetypes\maven-archetype-quickstart\1.1\m2e-lastUpdated.properties (Access is denied)."
```

2. I tried to create a simple project and then convert to Maven. This is successful but when I try to add dependency for selenium using the Add dependency wizard – I get following error

---

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.12.0

org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.12.0
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.getProjectFacade(MavenBuilder.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:pom:3.12.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:267)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:pom:3.12.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:904)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:1)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:678)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:268)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:238)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:149)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:192)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
    at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.execute(OkHttpAetherClient.java:207)
    at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.get(OkHttpAetherClient.java:153)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.getResponse(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:672)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.resumableGet(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:587)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:453)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:304)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 85 more”
```

Comment: For 1. see https://howtodoinjava.com/tools/eclipse/how-to-import-maven-remote-archetype-catalogs-in-eclipse/

Comment: You need to add .settings file inside .m2 folder if you are working inside organisation or any proxy